# How to use define to generate a byte array from int?

Tags: c

I want use a define to get the 4 bytes from an `int`. How should I write this define?

```
int k = 4;
unsigned char byteK[4];

byteK[0] = (unsigned char)k & 0xFF;
byteK[1] = (unsigned char)((k >> 8) & 0xFF);
byteK[2] = (unsigned char)((k >> 16) & 0xFF);
byteK[3] = (unsigned char)((k >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that (assuming that `int` on your machine is really 4 bytes):

```
#define INT_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var) ((unsigned char *)(&int_var))
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
int new_var = 0x11223344;

unsigned char byte0 = INT_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(new_var)[0];
unsigned char byte1 = INT_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(new_var)[1];
unsigned char byte2 = INT_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(new_var)[2];
unsigned char byte3 = INT_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(new_var)[3];
```

On my machine ([little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) I get:

> byte0=0x44 byte1=0x33 byte2=0x22 byte3=0x11

Comment: Remember that you'll need to write two (or more) versions of this, one for each endianness of your target platforms.

Comment: @TobySpeight, not me but @KenChu. Two for each endianness, one for `sizeof(int) == 2` and one for `sizeof(int)==4`. But if he needs it for some local task which is not a product or not going to be ported to other platforms then he may use only the one working version.

Comment: thank you so much, Alex Lop. that's what I need. but if it possible be
#define INT32_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var) {}, then return an unsigned char array[4], like unsigned char *temp = INT32_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var), and then I can get the byte value from temp

Comment: @KenChu, sorry, could you clarify what exactly do you want to define?

Comment: @Alex Lop. like unsigned char *temp = INT32_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var), and then temp[0] = 0x44, temp[1] = 0x33, ....

Comment: @KenChu, yes, of course. You can use it that way too.

Comment: when I use unsigned char *temp = INT32_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var), I got return of memory address of int_var.

Comment: @KenChu that's true, but now you treat it as `unsigned char arr[4]`.

Comment: @AlexLop. how to treat it as unsigned char arr[4], if I use unsigned char *temp = INT32_TO_4BYTE_ARRAY(int_var), it's same with unsigned char *temp = &int_var. how can I access temp[x] directly. sorry, I am not good in c language

Comment: @KenChu you can use `unsigned char *` as an array. It is the same. The C language allows it.

Comment: @AlexLop. but if I get the value from temp[x], I get unpredicted value. not the byte value of int_var.

Comment: @KenChu it is perfectly defined as long as `x` is less than 4.